# What type of tree has these purple berries

Tags: identification, trees, berries

I planted it a couple years ago thought it was an orange tree. Has an orange tree behind it to the right planted at the same time.

[image: Berry clusters[![tree]
[image]

Comment: Hi, Terri! Can you please tell us something about its location and post a close-up picture of the berries? It would speed up finding an answer.

Comment: I moved from Merced CA to Winton CA and I had an orange tree in the back yard of my old place and brought two Orange tree starts to my new place but one was this tree with purple berries the leaves on the starts looked identical so I thought it was an orange tree.  I don't see any of these trees in the old neighborhood.

Answer (score 3):

I would say you have a Privet, *Ligustrum* sp. Most likely *Ligustrum lucidum*, native to southern China but widely introduced where it has become an invasive species in some regions.

http://www.iewf.org/weedid/Ligustrum_lucidum.htm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligustrum_lucidum

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is Ligustrum sinense, Chinese Privet.

[Ligustrum sinense](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjv39WcveXYAhUB8GMKHWScBlIQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgobotany.newenglandwild.org%2Fspecies%2Fligustrum%2Fsinense%2F&psig=AOvVaw2RBqgHxhqDi-muq0d96beA&ust=1516501134092737)

Answer (score 0):

I would say its a privet of some type- just remember to wash your hands after handling any plant material , the plant is quite toxic.